# Magento Import / Add the attributes AFTER import?

Tags: magento, import, attributes

I have to import 4000 products from our old CMS website to the new Magento store. Those products have only name/title/description/price.

In the Magento shop all products will have many different attributes. I want to assign corresponding attributes to products later.

I made already a CSV template with the right columns.

My question is: Is is possible to import all products without any attributes and after import add attributes and attribute sets programmatically?

I'm wondering how to deal with this situation ??

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Anna

Answer (score 0):

You must always define the attribute set when you are creating the product. The attribute set is describing which attributes are assigned to the product. Take a look into [MAGMI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/). This tool is much faster and flexible that the default Magento importer.